# Reset/Un-select Select Option

Tags: php, jquery, select, reset

Usage:

I have a form that has a select drop-down that's controlled by another select drop-down. On loading the page (if values where selected before, PHP loads them) select drop-down #2 hides several options (this works). When selecting a particular option with select drop-down #1, select drop-down #2 hidden options become available (.show(), this works).

The problem: (An example to outline the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/RqhbY/7/)

When the hidden options are shown/available and one is selected and then the select drop-down #1 changes that value that hides the options in drop-down #2, On submission the selected hidden value gets submitted.

How can I un-select/reset the selected option that is now hidden?

Comment: Just wondering, are you working on some legacy code or something? Why the jQuery 1.3.2?

Comment: @Jasper yeah it's a older project anf there is so much older code that uses jQuery 1.3.2 that I can't upgrade it just yet. A complete rewrite is happening but that could take months and this needs to get fix ASAP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/RqhbY/8/

Try changing:

```
$('select[name=two[0]] option').attr('selected', false);
```

with:

```
$('select[name=two[0]] option').removeAttr('selected');
```

**UPDATE**

OK, I tested the above code in IE 8 and the disabled `<option>` is still selected. This seemed to work however:

```
$('select[name=two[0]]').children('option').removeAttr('selected').filter(':nth-child(1)').attr('selected', true);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RqhbY/9/

Note that you may want to update the `.filter()` call to only select non-disabled options but I'll leave that for you.

**UPDATE**

If you call `.attr('selectedIndex', -1)` on the `<select>` element then you can have no `<option>`s selected. The drop-down will not show a value but instead will be blank.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RqhbY/10/