# Jquery Mobile Select does not reset

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am writing a web shop with Jquery Mobile where I want to use a select menu to browse the categories available. When the user selects a category I want to navigate to the same page but with a couple of parameters added to the url. This is my markup for the select:

```
  <asp:Repeater id="productCatSelect" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                        <select id="productCatSelectMenu" data-native-menu="false" onchange="categoryClick();" class="button" data-theme="a">
                        <option data-placeholder="true">All Categories</option>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <option value="<%# Eval("NodeID") %>" ><%# Eval("Description")%></option>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </select>
                </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
function categoryClick() {
    var mySelect = $("#productCatSelectMenu");
    if (mySelect.val() != '') {
        if (mySelect.val() == 0) {
            $.mobile.changePage("shop.aspx", {reloadPage: true, transition:"slide"});
        } else {
            $.mobile.changePage("shop.aspx?c=" + $("#productCatSelectMenu").val() + "&n=" + $('#productCatSelectMenu :selected').text(), {reloadPage: true, transition:"slide"});
        }
    }
}
```

My problem occurs when I have navigated once and try to choose another option from the select, my javascript still retreives the previous value; the select does not seem to reset! However, when I press F5 and reload the page manually the menu works again, until I have used it once of course.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this? As you can see in the javascript the "reloadPage: true" attribute does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're going to need to reset this yourself, maybe try:

```
$('select#productCatSelectMenu option').attr('selected', false);
```

or

```
$('select#productCatSelectMenu option').removeAttr('selected');
```

or

```
$('select#productCatSelectMenu').children('option').removeAttr('selected').filter(':nth-child(1)').attr('selected', true);
```

or

```
$('select#productCatSelectMenu').attr('selectedIndex', -1);
```

I had a similar problem the other day

- [Reset/Un-select Select Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496722/reset-un-select-select-option)

Comment: It doesn't work unless adding `$('select#productCatSelectMenu').selectmenu("refresh");` , likes @user3679385 's answer,

Answer (score 10):

If you're using jQuery Mobile's custom select field, try

```
$("#select_id").selectmenu('refresh', true)
```

This will successfully reset the select options rendered by jQuery mobile.

Comment: If it can help others, i'm also with jQuery mobile and after looking for a long time on how to reset selects i came upon this solution based on Timothy's answer: `$("#form_id select").selectmenu('refresh', true);`

Comment: You may still need to remove the attr depending on the state the page is loaded. $("#select_id option").removeAttr('selected');

Answer (score 4):

I have no clue why Jquery mobile select is working the way it is. None of the above worked for me except for what is mentioned here. I am using the current versions
jquery-1.10.2.min.js
jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/resetting-select-menu

```
var myselect = $("select#useOfColor");
myselect[0].selectedIndex = 0;
myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `$('#productCatSelectMenu').selectmenu('refresh');`?

You can check information about the `refresh` method [in the documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/selects/methods.html)

Comment: This will refresh the jQM Controls but not the selectedIndex